# Data Loss in Kafka S3 Connector

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We are using Kafka S3 Connector for log pipeline, as it guarantees exactly-once semantics. However, we've experienced two data loss events on different topics. We found a suspicious error message in kafka-connect worker's log as below.

```
[2019-04-10 08:56:22,388] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=s3-sink-common-log-4} Commit of offsets threw an unexpected exception for sequence number 2721: {logging_common_log-9=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=4485661604, metadata=''}, logging_common_log-8=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=4485670359, metadata=''}} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:260)
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.sendOffsetCommitRequest(ConsumerCoordinator.java:808)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.doCommitOffsetsAsync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:641)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsAsync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:608)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitAsync(KafkaConsumer.java:1486)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.doCommitAsync(WorkerSinkTask.java:352)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.doCommit(WorkerSinkTask.java:363)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.commitOffsets(WorkerSinkTask.java:432)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:209)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:193)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The configs of worker and connector are:

```
{
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
  "flush.size": "999999999",
  "rotate.schedule.interval.ms": "60000",
  "retry.backoff.ms": "5000",
  "s3.part.retries": "3",
  "s3.retry.backoff.ms": "200",
  "s3.part.size": "26214400",
  "tasks.max": "3",
  "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
  "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
  "schema.compatibility": "NONE",
  "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner",
  "timestamp.extractor": "Record",
  "partition.duration.ms": "3600000",
  "path.format": "YYYY/MM/dd/HH",
  "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "locale": "US",
  "append.late.data": "false",
  ...
},
```

and

```
    group.id=connect-cluster
    key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    key.converter.schemas.enable=false
    value.converter.schemas.enable=false
    offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
    offset.storage.replication.factor=3
    offset.storage.partitions=25
    config.storage.topic=connect-configs
    config.storage.replication.factor=3
    status.storage.topic=connect-status
    status.storage.replication.factor=3
    status.storage.partitions=5
    rest.port=8083
    plugin.path=/usr/local/share/java,/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins,/opt/connectors,
    plugin.path=/usr/share/java
```

The questions are:
1. What's the root cause?
2. How to prevent it?
3. How to reproduce it?

Thank you very much for any hints/advice/similar experience!

Comment: The only way records would be lost was if you let them expire on the topic. This is true for all Connectors, not just S3 Connect... If the offsets didn't get commited, then S3 Connect should retry the consumption

Comment: Have you been able to solve the issue? We are experiencing the a similar issue on the s3-sink and can somewhat correlate it to the 'CommitFailedException' log events.

Comment: Maybe this issue is relevant which also involves data loss in Kafka Connect S3-sink:
https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/issues/253